# How to remove in-text citations using python

Tags: python, text, nltk

What would be the process of deleting citations?

For example a text file may contain these variations:

```
1.Smith & Smith 2016 stressed "Johnny Johnny Yes Papa" p(5).
```

expected output: stressed.

```
2. Smith, Smith & Smith 2016
```

expected output: -- nothing, the entire sting is deleted.

```
3. Smith et al. 2015
```

expected output: -- nothing, the entire sting is deleted.

```
4. [18]
```

expected output: -- nothing, the entire sting is deleted.

```
5  (Smith & Smith 2016: 326)
```

expected output: -- nothing, the entire sting is deleted.

it would be nice to just wipe these clean. Because when you run the frequency analysis, citations skew things quite a bit.

Your input is greatly  appreciated.

Comment: you could use regex to remove them

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> a = """1.Smith & Smith 2016 stressed "Johnny Johnny Yes Papa" p(5). 2. Smith, Smith & Smith 2016 3. Smith et al. 2015 4. [18] 5 (Smith & Smith 2016: 326)"""
>>> re.sub(r'"[^"]*"','***', a)
'1.Smith & Smith 2016 stressed *** p(5). 2. Smith, Smith & Smith 2016 3. Smith et al. 2015 4. [18] 5 (Smith & Smith 2016: 326)'
```

It also works with more quotes in the string:

```
>>> b = """Hallo "H.urz" Welt "hurz" Wie geht's?"""
>>> re.sub(r'"[^"]*"','***', b)
"Hallo *** Welt *** Wie geht's?"
```

But maybe I misinterpret the question. Maybe you want to specify your requirement in the question in a little bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you, the regex would address anything with either the brackets or quotation marks.  Identifying name and year as in Smith et al. 2015 and Smith, Smith & Smith 2016 is a bit more tricky. And if everything is in lower case, there are no capital letters to even suggest that this is the name. There is et al. and there is  comma, &.